# Recurrence relation to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

It seems clear that one method to solve recurrence relation is the transformation to a differential equation as follows $$a_{n+k}\to f^{(k)}$$
I'm trying to modelize this easy problem: "Given a bottle filled with water, I drink every day half of the water present". This leads to $$x(n+1)=\frac{1}{2}x(n)$$ The transformation here is $f'=1/2f$ which has the solution $ce^{t/2}$, which is not the model of the problem, since it diverges. What am I missing here?
Could someone give some a clear explanation for the relation between the rec. rel. and the ode applied to this case? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example where this transformation works?

Comment: @saulspatz you can see this for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773205/relation-between-differential-equations-and-sequence-recursions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it "continuously"

$$
\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{\Delta t}= -\gamma x_n
$$

then

$$
x_{n+1}=(1-\gamma\Delta t)x_n
$$