# How to solve the nonlinear recurrence which depends on $n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Given a nonlinear recurrence equation $a_{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{n+1 + a_{n}}$ and $a_0 = 0$. Is there any way to derive the closed-form of $a_n$?

---

The sequence is increasing and bounded above by $1$. So I tried to find the fixed point $x = \frac{n}{n+ x}$, then $x = \frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 4n} - n}{2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{n}} + 1}$. But it seems not correct since the value depends on $n$. I am not sure what can we say about it?

---

I am looking for methods to deal with recurrence in the fraction form and depending on $n$. It seems there are some methods described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Examples) using differential equations. But it does not fit the form.

---

Here is the graph for the sequence starting from $a_2$ (blue) and the sequence $b_n = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{n}} + 1}$. They are quite close. Is there any theorem to show these two sequences are close?

[image]

Comment: Please add some context for your problem, such as where you encountered it or what you've already tried or researched before posting.  Often the motivation for a math problem is a good starting point for searching for solutions.

Comment: I wonder why there is the [tag:partial-differential-equations] tag. Also what is the value of $a_1$?

Comment: @WhatsUp See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773205/relation-between-differential-equations-and-sequence-recursions

Comment: As far as I can tell, differential equations are totally irrelevant here. You still didn't answer my other question: what is $a_1$? It seems to be $\frac00$ according to your definition.

Comment: @WhatsUpThanks.  I corrected the typo. $a_1 = 1$. $\Delta(a_n) = a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{n+1}{n+1+a_n} - a_n$. Then it's difference equation.

Comment: With your new version, the numerator is [A000166](http://oeis.org/A000166) and the denominator is [A000255](http://oeis.org/A000255). I don't think there is a general closed formula for that.

Comment: The fixed point approach doesn’t really do much good, since it is a function of $n.$

Comment: @WhatsUp I cannot understand what is A000166? Actually, I am looking for methods for such problems. If no closed form, a closed lower bound is also very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. @ThomasAndrews Is there any other method to analyze the recurrence?

Comment: The limit is easily seen to be $1,$ since $0\leq a_n\leq 1$ means $\frac{n+1}{n+2}\leq a_{n+1}\leq 1.$ Closed form of $a_n,$ not sure. Have you computed the first bunch of values?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, right. I just added a graph for the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=2}^{100}$. It seems it convergence to 1 fast and is concave.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Interestingly, when I plot the sequence defined by $b_n = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{n}} + 1}$. It is almost the same as $a_n$.

Comment: One solution is $a_n=(n+1)/(n+2)$. This is asymptotically the same as your approximation. The error terms are approximately $\epsilon (-1)^n/n!$, so all solutions rapidly converge to $(n+1)/(n+2)$

Comment: @Eric Thanks. How to show the error term?

Comment: Plug in $(n+1)/(n+2)+\epsilon$, simplify the expression with the assumption that n is big and $\epsilon$ is small to get something like the $n+1$st error term being around $-\epsilon(n+2)/(n+1)(n+3)$, so around $-\epsilon/n$

Answer (score 2):

We have $0 \leq a_n \leq 1$ then :
$$\dfrac{n + 1}{n + 2} \leq a_{n + 1} \leq 1$$
We deduce that $a_n \to 1$.